# Is a 1.5-hour transfer in Munich doable?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airport-transfer

I'm going from Glasgow to Frankfurt, and then land in Munich in terminal 2 with Lufthansa. I have 1.5 hours to get to terminal 1 for Oman air. Does this leave me enough time?

Comment: So it is two stops in Germany? Requiring you to enter the Schengen area in Frankfurt and exciting it in Munich? Is arriving in Munich and leaving with Oman air on one ticket?

Comment: Yeah but on the website it says point of origin so this would be out of the schengen area? or is that wrong? it’s all booked through lufthansa.

Comment: If it are two stops in Germany you will need to pass through immigration twice. If it is one stop in Germany you will not pass through immigration at all.

Comment: so passing immigration twice at munich or one at frankfurt and then munich?

Comment: Into Schengen at Frankfurt, out of Schengen in Munich.

Comment: Just to be clear: Would you need a visa for entering the Schengen area? If yes, then you would need to get a visa for this trip, too.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a single ticket: easy. 1.5 hours is plenty. Even if you miss it you will get rebooked for free.

If these are two separate tickets: Extremely risky. Not impossible but you would have to get very lucky. Details like checked luggage, status, class of service matter a lot here. Don't do it.

Comment: Perfect yes it’s all booked through Lufthansa so one ticket! Thank you so much

Comment: One note on the free rebooking: While it's true that you will be rebooked for free, there are a few caveats. I just checked the flights run by Oman Air from MUC, and they leave Munich late in the evening. Rebooking means you will probably have to spend the night in Munich (Lufthansa will pay for the hotel), and the next day they might reroute you through other airports, or make you wait for 24 hours for the next direct flight - either way, be prepared to arrive 12 to 24 hours later than planned if you miss the flight.

Answer (score 0):

I made a trip through Munich Airport from USA to Israel. I had 2 hours to walk through from landing to the next gate. It was a bit rough for me because of mobility issues. We had to walk through a controlled part of the airport through a border check before entering a waiting area for the flight from Munich to Israel. If you do not have mobility issues, you should be fine in 90 minutes as you will already have passed basic airport security in Frankfurt and be inside the airport security lines in Munich. The customs/passport checkpoint I passed through was only for those who were on that flight.

It sounds like you will have a customs check for entry into Germany at Frankfurt. But you may have a passport control check like I did. It was quick.

So I think you will be fine as Lufthansa planned everything via their booking. Call Lufthansa & look at the airport information below. It looks like there is a shuttle bus between Terminals 1 & 2. Safe travels.

- Munich Airport Connecting info:
  https://www.munich-airport.com/connecting-flights-260553
- Frankfurt Airport connecting info:
  https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights-and-transfer/transferring-at-fra.html